# Want to add padding if the item is shown - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have this jQuery snippet:

```
$("#rectangle").hide();
$("#toggle-rec").click(function () {
      $("#rectangle").toggle(2000);
});
```

It means that I have a rectnagle div in my site, and firstly I hide him. When someone clicks on button that with id `#toggle-rec`, the rectangle is displayed. In the next click the rectangle will disappear and so on.

But, I want to do that if the rectangle is shown, padding-left the whole website (except from the rectangle) 200 px (as the rectangle's width), so:

```
padding-left:200px;
```

But I still don't know how to do it. Of course that if the rectangle disappear, we should cancel the padding-left or something. Any suggestions?

**Please note that all site except the rectangle is under wrapper div.**

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="rectangle">
Some text on the rectangle...
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- A lot of things... -->
<button id="toggle-rec">Toggle rectangle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Comment: are u talking about off canvas layout?? http://www.zell-weekeat.com/off-canvas-layouts-susy/

Comment: Yes, and I edited the code and added the HTML @madhairsilence

Comment: Can not you use this? `if($("#rectangle").is(":visible")){//padding-left the body}`

Comment: @WebR I gave u a tutorial url. Please follow that. You are trying to reinvent the wheel and there is no challenge in this

Comment: I can use the padding-left like that? or I should write css or something before it? @Justcode

Comment: I guess adding class will be good.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to do it? @Justcode

Comment: @WebR http://jsbin.com/xuwetiloka/edit?html,css,js,output have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just to use .toggleClass.

```
$("#rectangle").hide();
$("#toggle-rec").click(function () {
  $("#rectangle").toggle(1000);
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("leftpadwrapper")
});
```

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0kswh693/4/

and this animates it

```
#wrapper{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Its works. But one more thing - Its look "bad" when they move - like static or something. Do you have any idea how to put effect when I toggle between classes? @apikurious

Comment: @WebR if you take a look at my fiddle(updated link) you can see i added css transitions for the wrapper. that animates it

Comment: Are they the things that on the "#wrapper {" block?

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Please check demo

```js
$("#rectangle").hide();
$("#toggle-rec").click(function () {
   $("#rectangle").toggle(2000).promise().done(function() { 
     if($("#rectangle").css('display') == 'none') 
     {
       $('body').removeClass('leftMargin');
     }
     else {
       $('body').addClass('leftMargin'); 
     }
   }); 
});
```

```css
.leftMargin
{
  padding-left:200px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectangle">
Some text on the rectangle...
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- A lot of things... -->
<button id="toggle-rec">Toggle rectangle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats worked too. But you can just use "toggleClass" like apikurious suggested to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want something like this. With the info provided above, I can provide this solution.

```
$("#toggle-rec").click(function () {
 $("#rectangle").toggle(function(){
   if($('#rectangle').is(':visible')){
    $('body').css({'padding-left':'200px'})
   }
   else{
    $('body').css({'padding-left':0})
   }
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the first "if" is worked, but the "else" is not. You forgot a "0" instead of just 0, but I try it too without success. You have any idea why the "else" statment doesn't work? @SumitSahay

Comment: 0 & '0' doesn't make a difference here.
but the above code should work.
You can try using else if($('#rectangle').is(':hidden')){}
But its good you got your ans

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#rectangle").hide();
$("#toggle-rec").click(function () {
       $("#rectangle").toggle(2000);
       if($("#rectangle").is(":visible"))
       {
          $("#wrapper").removeClass("body-left-padding");
       }
       else
       {
          $("#wrapper").addClass("body-left-padding");
       }
});
```

```css
#rectangle
{
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}
.body-left-padding
{
  padding-left: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="rectangle">
    Some text on the rectangle...
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- A lot of things... -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consequat est magna, vel vehicula augue efficitur ac. Vestibulum imperdiet eros dolor, ac vulputate felis tempor hendrerit. Ut eleifend diam ligula, ut ullamcorper est laoreet non. Mauris blandit risus in mi elementum, in feugiat ligula aliquet. Ut consequat at dolor nec scelerisque. Nullam condimentum fringilla dui non maximus. Ut sit amet erat ac eros viverra porttitor. Cras lobortis eleifend lacus eu egestas. Aenean pellentesque, erat eu dignissim congue, neque mi semper mauris, et eleifend leo dolor nec mi. Vivamus et vehicula magna. Aenean sit amet tincidunt quam, quis dapibus nisi. Aenean suscipit sem enim, sit amet rutrum urna tincidunt eu.</p>
    <button id="toggle-rec">Toggle rectangle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hey said padding left.. where is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#rectangle").hide();
   isPadding = false;
   padding_left = 0;
   $("#toggle-rec").click(function () {
        if(isPadding){
         //$("#rectangle").toggle(2000);
         //$("#rectangle" ).contents().css("color", "red");
         padding_left = 0;
         isPadding = false;
         }
        else{
         padding_left = 20;
         isPadding = true;
        }
        $("#rectangle").toggle(2000);       
        $("#rectangle" ).children().css("padding-left", padding_left);
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="rectangle">
<label>Some text on the rectangle...</label>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- A lot of things... -->
<button id="toggle-rec">Toggle rectangle</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```